# Knockout dropdownlist from AJAX data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with data taken from an AJAX call.

I am new to Knockout and just can't figure out how it accepts a dynamic array of data.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<select data-bind="options: jobTitles, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id' value: selectedItem"></select>
```

And the script is called on AJAX success:

```
function UserViewModel(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    this.surname = ko.observable(data.Surname);

    JobTitlesList: ko.observableArray([]);

    $.each(data.TitlesList, function(index, value) {
        JobTitlesList.push(value)
    });

    jobTitles : ko.observableArray(JobTitlesList[])
}
```

The Knockout documentation shows how to do a dropdownlist but not one with dynamic data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the ajax callback function ?

Comment: And also please post a sample of the `data` object sent as parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are recreating your entire viewmodel after ajax completion.  You should just update your list on ajax completion with

```
function UpdateDropDown(data) {
    $.each(data.TitlesList, function(index, value) {
        JobTitlesList.push(value)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your right but there is more to it than just the dropdownlist. Otherwise I would agree with you.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question then.  Overall comment still stands...create your viewmodel, then update it with your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

For anyone else new to knockout, this is how I did it:

```
this.jobTitlesList = ko.observableArray(data.TitlesList);

this.jobTitles = this.jobTitlesList;
this.selectedItem = 213;
```

Where data.TitlesList is the array coming back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
function UserViewModel(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    this.surname = ko.observable(data.Surname);
    this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    this.jobTitles = ko.observableArray([]);
    var mappedjobTitles = $.map(data.TitlesList, function (item) {
                        return new JobTitle(item)
                    });

    this.jobTitles(mappedjobTitles);
}
```

You can define the default value of the selectedItem observable or you can add an additional parameter to the  node like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: jobTitles, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id' value: selectedItem" optionsCaption: "Select a job title..."></select>
```

Make sure the TitlesList contains an array of objects with properties 'name' and 'id'; in case the TitlesList is just an array of strings, then should get rid of the 
optionsText and optionsValue parameters.